# ATOM (Cosmos) Staking API shows huge rewards numbers

Tags: java, transactions, cryptocurrency, cosmos-sdk

I am using the method [here](https://docs.cosmos.network/v0.44/core/proto-docs.html#cosmos.distribution.v1beta1.QueryDelegationRewardsRequest) (QueryDelegationRewardsRequest) in java to try to get a delegator's rewards with a validator, and I get `43,959,458,898,830,411,000,000,000 uatom`, whereas in the blockchain scanner it shows `50531742 uatom`. Is this not the correct method to get an address's rewards? If so, what is the right one and what does this massive number even mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the result you are given is in a decimal number with a 18 scale, even though it doesn't show the dot anywhere, so the number above is equal to `43959458 uatom`